# Connection attempt from disallowed node on ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd

Having and issue with an ejabberd cluster. While trying ping the first node from the second, I'm getting :

"Connection attempt from disallowed node"

I know it's not a cookie issue, because the cookies on both servers match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know it's not a cookie issue,
>   because the cookies on both servers
>   match.

Just to be sure, did you checked that both nodes are indeed using the same cookie value,  you can use 
`erlang:get_cookie().`
to get the cookie in use.